# jQuery on scroll-event not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

Im trying to have the below code run in Internet Explorer 11, but cant seem to make it. It runs well in both Chrome, Firefox and Opera, but in IE11 nothing happens. Does anyone happen to know how to fix it? It is a simple code that adds some classes and changes css-settings upon scrolling.

**jQuery/Javascript:**

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
        $('#soyle1').addClass('soyle1').css('height', '400px');
        $('#soyle2').addClass('soyle2').css('height', '480px');
        $('#soyle3').addClass('soyle3').css('height', '320px');
        $('#soyle4').addClass('soyle4').css('height', '400px');         
}); //End scroll-function
```

Comment: Add a fiddle or plunk. $(window).on('scroll' fn) works great in IE11

Comment: @RonGilchrist Thanks, I tried storing the function in a variable named fn, and instead doing $(window).on('scroll', fn). No difference in IE11 though. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Here is a simplified fiddle that works in IE - you might be missing something like running that code on ready... http://jsfiddle.net/p7zm4yjv/1/

Comment: On a separate note, you're going to bombard those four elements with redundant instructions to add a class, and set additional inline styles literally dozens of times a second?

Comment: @RonGilchrist Thanks! I might/must be..

Comment: @JonathanSampson Good point. I'm finishing it off with a $(window).off('scroll'); now. :)

Comment: @danjah jQuery `$.fn.one` method may be a appropriate. It automatically unbinds itself after firing once.

Answer (score 1):

even though you got an answer for the scrolling part. wanted to add an answer about how to minimize the redundancy with the code in the fiddle. there are different approaches to doing this(debounce, throttle, timeout etc), but the simplest in my eyes is the run-once. it simply depends on a Boolean which changes its state after the function was triggered once.

```
runonce = false;
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if (!runonce) {
    $('#s1').addClass('s1').css('height', '400px');
    $('#s2').addClass('s2').css('height', '480px');
    ...
    runonce = true;
  }
});
```